# I can't install react using npx create-react-app? why

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I can't install react using npx create-react-app?
and the log file of the error is here...!
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -4055
npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
npm ERR! nospc There appears to be insufficient space on your system to finish.
npm ERR! nospc Clear up some disk space and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\سلمى\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-18T23_42_10_453Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting session/ from C:\Users\sl
Done.

How I can get rid of this trouble??

Comment: I would assume you don't have space on your disk. Check how much free space you have, and check *where* the system is trying to install things. Is it using some sort of temporary file system? A network disk? A ramdisk? etc

Comment: Potential resource: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1131

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i think you should move the target directory disk (partition) of installation for npm in your environtment. I can suggest it to you, after i read the error message that you attach to us.

> Clear up some disk space and try again

But if you still want to install it at your current partition, you should to do one of these suggestion:

- Move some files from your partion (for best result, i recommend to move the large file/ more than 1 GB files).
- Delete some unused files (for best result, i recommend to delete the large file/ more than 1 GB files).
- Clear your computer cache (but i think it was not significant)

After that, you can continue your progress of installation.

Hope it was helpful.

Thank you